# How can I query XML data in SSRS / VS 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report query using a lot of WITH XMLNAMESPACES to query some XML data in SQL Server 2008. It doesn't look like i can create a report in VS 2008 using this query because of the xml querying. If I'm reading MS's [whitepaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) correctly, you have to pull the XML out and then do a separate query against it? Anyone have any experience with this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And this is an issue of misinterpreting errors. The real issue in my query wasn't the use of WITH XMLNAMESPACES, but the use of "sql:variable("@varName") in the WHERE of my XSL. Easy way to solve that is to add a DECLARE @varName  in the query and set it to the passed in parameter. After that, it worked like a champ.